# Build tiles from a feature collection

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to create tiles given a collection of features.

**UPDATE**

Let's say I got two tiles per zoom level 1 and my features are about a small area near Berlin. I expect one of the two tiles empty and the other one filled with all the features with proper dimension (I expect to see something like a point because features are about a small area). What I get is an empty tile (correct) and a image 256 x 256 representing the features like it was a thumbnail, not a tile.

This is what I did so far to render features in a tile:

```
...
MapContent content = new MapContent();
GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
ReferencedEnvelope mapArea = featureCollection.getBounds();
Style shpStyle = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureCollection.getSchema());
Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, shpStyle);
content.addLayer(layer);
renderer.setMapContent(content);
Rectangle tileArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, 256, 256);
renderer.paint(graphics, tileArea, mapArea);
File fileToSave = File.createTempFile("mytesttile.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", fileToSave);
...
```

but this code produces a small (256 x 256) image of the given collection, not a tile. I am in short of time and I can't find some good docs or a working example. Can you point me to the right direction? I am using geotools version `17.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the right path, just confusing rendering areas. `mapArea` must represent the area your tile want to cover about the entire map. I just change my code this way.

```
...
ReferencedEnvelope mapArea = new ReferencedEnvelope(tile.getEnvelope().getEastCoordinateMin(),
    tile.getEnvelope().getEastCoordinateMax(), tile.getEnvelope().getNorthCoordinateMin(),
    tile.getEnvelope().getNorthCoordinateMax(), org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));
Style shpStyle = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureCollection.getSchema());
Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, shpStyle);
content.addLayer(layer);
renderer.setMapContent(content);
Rectangle imageArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
renderer.paint(graphics, imageArea, mapArea);
...
```

`tileArea` variable name changed in `imageArea`, it still implements tile's size.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you need to divide your map up into however many rows and columns you need and then draw a tile for each column/row pair. So in pseudo code:

```
for i in rows
  for j in cols
     bbox=calculateBBox(i,j);
     map.setExtent(bbox);
     renderTile(i,j,bbox);
```

You don't say what style of tile output you need, so aligning to a tile matrix or tileset and handling zoom levels etc is left as an exercise.

Comment: Sorry I was pretty unclear, I update my question. Thanks.